# How to hide COM errors?

Tags: error-handling, runtime-error, try-catch, autoit, suppress-warnings

My code works but in the `WebRequest` part, if the system is offline, an error appears:

> "cannot resolve this address"

The WebRequest works when an internet connection exists. Can I hide this error?

```
#include <StringConstants.au3>
#include <Array.au3>
#include <String.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <InetConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>

Opt("RunErrorsFatal", 0)

Global $eRRor = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error","MyErrFunction")

Func MyErrFunction()
 ; empty function
Endfunc

...some code here...

$oweb = ObjCreate("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1");
$oweb.Open("POST",$TheUrl , False); ;Error happens here
$oweb.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/(a type)");
$oweb.SetRequestHeader("User-Agent", "(a random user agent)");
$oweb.Send($content);

...other code...
```

I have tried this as well:

```
If @error Then  
    Exit
EndIf
```

But I want to continue if the error (silently) happens.

[image: error screenshot]

This is the error from the compiled script (.exe file). The code on line 8047 is `$oweb.Send($content);` But on debugging with error details enabled:

[image: COM error]

This happens on `$oweb.Open("POST",$TheUrl , False);`.

Comment: Does it help to check whether the internet connection is alive before using the object.

Answer (score 0):

I missed that you already use:

```
Global $eRRor = ObjEvent("AutoIt.Error","MyErrFunction")
```

Just modyfi

```
Func MyErrFunction($oError)
  ; do nothing
EndFunc
```